# ValueError: Shapes (426530, 2) and (1930, 2) are incompatible for y_pred and y_test

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, nlp

I am working on the DistillBert project for binary classification. I am trying to run the following code using the Spam SMS data set (You can also use the IMDB dataset, it is also giving the same issue), I am trying to find out the recall, precision, and AUC score. However, I am getting a Value error.

Here I am using the `BinaryCrossentropy` loss function and `Adam` optimizer.

Dataset: The dataset used here is the spam SMS dataset which has binary labels 0 for standard SMS and 1 for spam SMS. The same error can be reproduced using the IMDB data set for this code.

Error:

```
ValueError: Shapes (426530, 2) and (1930, 2) are incompatible
```

I am getting this error right on running the tab containing this code:

```
m = tf.keras.metrics.Recall()
m.update_state(y_test_encoded, y_pred)
m.result().numpy()
```

Here y_pred is the predicted labels and y_test_encoded is the one-hot encoded ground truth labels. the `test_dataset` used here for prediction is tokenized test data converted to the TensorFlow dataset using from_tensor_slices.
I am assuming that the problem is because of the different shapes of the predicted and the ground truth labels.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import transformers
from transformers import DistilBertTokenizer
from transformers import TFAutoModelForSequenceClassification
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
MODEL_NAME = 'distilbert-base-uncased'
BATCH_SIZE = 8
N_EPOCHS = 3

train = pd.read_csv("train_set.csv", error_bad_lines=False)
test = pd.read_csv("test_set.csv", error_bad_lines=False)

X_train = train.text
X_test = test.text
y_train = train.label
y_test = test.label

#One-hot encoding of labels
y_train_encoded = tf.one_hot(y_train.values, 2)
y_test_encoded = tf.one_hot(y_test.values, 2)

tokenizer = DistilBertTokenizer.from_pretrained(MODEL_NAME)

train_encodings = tokenizer(list(X_train.values),
                        truncation=True, 
                        padding=True)
test_encodings = tokenizer(list(X_test.values),
                       truncation=True, 
                       padding=True)

train_dataset = 
tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(train_encodings),list(y_train_encoded)))

test_dataset = 
tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(test_encodings),list(y_test_encoded)))
test_dataset2 = test_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1024).take(1000).batch(16)

model = TFAutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(MODEL_NAME)

optimizerr = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=5e-5)

losss = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy((from_logits=True)

model.compile(optimizer=optimizerr,
          loss=losss,
          metrics=['accuracy'])

print("Evaluate Base model on test data")
results = model.evaluate(test_dataset2)
print("test loss, test acc:", results)

model.fit(train_dataset.shuffle(len(X_train)).batch(BATCH_SIZE),
      epochs=N_EPOCHS,
      batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)

predictions = model.predict(test_dataset)


y_pred = tf.round(tf.nn.sigmoid(predictions.logits))

m = tf.keras.metrics.Recall()
m.update_state(y_test_encoded, rounded_predictions)
m.result().numpy()
# This is where I getting the above-mentioned error.
```

How can I fix the error and get the recall, precision and AUC scores?

Comment: What's the shape of `y_test_encoded` and `predictions`

Comment: @Djinn ```predictions ```- (426530, 2) and ```y_test_encoded``` -(1930, 2)

Comment: You are passing `y_test_encoded`, which based on your code, is a (larger) superset of `test_dataset2`. You need to pass the same input data used for `.predict()` when comparing predictions and true labels. You'd need to get the labels from `test_dataset2` and compare with `rounded_predictions` (assuming that comes from `predictions`).

Comment: @Djinn I made a mistake in editing the code for StackOverflow. I have indeed used `test_dataset` for predictions. After which the error was produced. I have updated the code above.

Comment: No, the issue isn't that you're predicting using `test_dataset`, it's that you're *not* comparing the predictions to `test_dataset`.

Comment: Refer to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

OP is predicting on the test set, but comparing the predictions with the original, larger dataset.

```
predictions = model.predict(test_dataset)  # this data needs to be used for comparison below
```

Change:

```
m.update_state(y_test_encoded, rounded_predictions)
```

To include labels from the dataset on `.predict()`:

```
true_labels = # labels from test_dataset
m.update_state(true_labels, rounded_predictions)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I understood what the issue is. However, when I am extracting the labels from `test_dataset` I am getting a 1D array with shape (3860,). and when I checked the length of labels in the `test_dataset` its 1930. I used the following code to extract the labels `labels =  np.array([])
for x, y in test_dataset:
    labels = np.concatenate([labels, y.numpy()])`

Comment: Also,the prediction is in the following form: `tf.Tensor(
[[1. 0.]
 ...
 [1. 0.]], shape=(426530, 2), dtype=float32)` How can the prediction label's length be 426530 while the original label's length is 1930?

Comment: You probably don't need to iterate over the dataset. You can copy the contents. If you're seeing the length is 1930 (which it should be), then something is being added in maybe?

Comment: content is the `y_test_encoded`  comes from line: ```test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(test_encodings),list(y_test_encoded ))) ```.  should directly use the `y_test_encoded` then? And yes some thing seems to have been added in the predictions as I checked the `predictions.logits` length is 426530. However the length of the original test labels is 1930

Comment: The shape of original test labels is (1930,2) and that of `test_dataset` is (221,) `<TensorSliceDataset shapes: ({input_ids: (221,), attention_mask: (221,)}, (2,)), types: ({input_ids: tf.int32, attention_mask: tf.int32}, tf.float32)> ` 1930x221 426530. test_encodings mentioned in the above comments is output after tokenization of X_test (parameters of the original test set). how do you think this can be fixed?

Comment: I'm not that experienced with tokenization in keras so i probably can't help much with that. Have you tried without doing that?